# How to output an array of images?

Tags: php, image

I am trying to list (also re size) photos in the following code. So I want to output all images with "x" id.

The problem is I have a heading I had included in the document so I can't use `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` to output the array of images I want to be shown. But if I take it out, it just shows a bunch of random characters, which I know is a photo in a string. I am not sure how to make this work. I plan to have each photo in its own div too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <?php include 'topheader.php'; ?>
        </head>

        <body>
            <?php
                ob_start();
                ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);
                $roomid = $_GET['room'];
                $query = "SELECT `photoname` FROM `roomsite`.`photos` WHERE `roomid`='$roomid'";
                $getphotos = $connect->prepare($query);
                if ($getphotos->execute()){
                    while ($array = $getphotos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('userphotos/'.$array['photoname'].'');


                        list($image_width, $image_height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('userphotos/'.$array['photoname'].'');

                        $new_size = ($image_width + $image_height)/($image_width*($image_height/100));
                        $new_width = $image_width * $new_size;
                        $new_height = $image_height * $new_size;

                        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                        imagecopyresized($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
                        $imagearray = imagejpeg($new_image, null);

                        header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
                        echo $imagearray;


                    }
                } else { die('Query Error'); }
            ?>
        </body>


    </html>
```

I can do something like this

```
while ($array = $getphotos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   echo '<img src="outputphotos.php">';
}
```

But then that means I will be running a query twice which probably isn't a good idea? Is that the only way?

Comment: Why do you even need to use image functions for this? You have the image file already, why not just link to it and use the `width` and `height` attributes to let the browser resize it for you? If there's that much of a difference in size, you should consider just saving the image in different sizes on your server.

Comment: @animuson Well I need to keep the ratios of the images the same which the code I used to resize the image does. I could just do: `while ($array = $getphotos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){    
 echo '<img src="userphotos/'.$array['photoname'].'">';
}`   But I need the images resized and the same ratio.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP protocol handles a single answer, to a single question. The way HTML works is that it describes structure and content in a single HTML document, and allows secondary resources to be loaded by reference. The correct way to do this is to generate `img` tags in your HTML to the pictures that need to be shown, also allowing you to style them etc. In the referenced URLs you can then take a parameter to the specific image.

Pseudocode:

```
while($row = $myQuery->nextRow())
    echo '<img src="/showimage.php?id='.$row->getId().
         ' alt="'.htmlentities($row->getName()).'">';
```

Since images are by definition standalone files you cannot in any way send them in the same request as the referencing document.

Comment: It is *technically* possible to embed an image directly into the HTML, but it's a really, *really* bad idea.

Comment: Yeah well data-URLs are possible, but I try not to give really, *really* bad ideas in answers to really, *really* basic questions  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you *really do* need dynamic image resizing, you can write a separate script for that. Something like:

```
http://yourdomain.com/DynamicImage.php?image=foo.png&maxwidth=100&maxheight=100
```

Then route all of your IMG tags there:

```
<img src="http://yourdomain.com/DynamicImage.php?image=originalImageName.jpg&maxwidth=100&maxheight=100" />
```

You could teach the script to cache the resulting resized images and serve them directly on future requests.